# Why does my htm pages have a number attached at the end of the link?

Tags: googlebot

When I wanted to fetch a certain page with `htm` extension I noticed an attachment after the htm extenstion `http://www.example.com/IP_814.htm#.Uk1_MtKsh8E`  Google could not fetch this page it gave the  502 error code.

When I fetched the same page as `http://www.example.com/IP_814.htm` Google fetched it and gave me the green check.

When I created the page, I named it `IP_814` with extension `htm` as this is a individual internal product page.  I believe that the code or number behind the `htm` changes daily.

What should I do so Google crawls my individual product pages with the `htm` extension?

Comment: When you say "google fetched it", are you referring to the "fetch as Googlebot" feature in Google webmaster tools?

Comment: Yes I was referring to "Fetched as googlebot"

Answer (score 1):

A `#` and anything following in a URL is a [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier).  It instructs the browser to fetch the page from the server that is specified by the portion before the `#` and then show the user the portion of the page identified by the fragment.  This is often implemented as scrolling the page to the appropriate section, but the JavaScript on the page may examine the fragment and take another action such as showing a specific DHTML tab.

When URLs are requested, the fragment identifier is never sent to the server.  Browsers must strip this information from the URL before making the request.  Googlebot should never be crawling URLs with fragments.  It should be stripping the fragment off before crawling the URL.

Comment: OH I think you answered my question, because I was the one who entered the whole link in webmaster google for the link to be fetched as google. The second time without knowing I stripped the fragment identifier, and that's why google was able to fetch my page. Thank you so much for explaining it to me!

Comment: I would expect that even if you entered it into the "fetch as Googlebot" tool that it would strip it off before it fetched it, but they may have a bug in that tool caused by an oversight of that case.